# Displaying a picture in an image control from stream

Tags: vb.net, caching, outputstream, cache-control, system.drawing

I created a generic handler `ImageResizer.ashx` that calls the function `ResizeImage(bmSource, intWidth)` and resizes the image and returns the output as `image/jpeg`

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="ImageResizer" %>

Imports System.Drawing

Public Class ImageResizer : Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Try
        Dim strImageName As String = configurationmanager.AppSettings("BasePath").ToString & "/" & context.Request.QueryString("image").Replace(configurationmanager.AppSettings("LivePath").ToString, "")
        Dim intWidth As Integer = CInt(context.Request.QueryString("w"))
        Dim bmSource As New Bitmap(strImageName)

        context.Response.Clear()
        context.Response.ClearHeaders()
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & DateTime.UtcNow().ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".jpg")
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"

        Using resizedImage As Bitmap = ResizeImage(bmSource, intWidth)
            bmSource.Dispose()
            resizedImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End Using

        context.Response.Flush()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

Private Function ResizeImage(bmSource As Bitmap, TargetWidth As Int32) As Bitmap
    Dim nSourceAspectRatio = bmSource.Width / bmSource.Height
    Dim TargetHeight = TargetWidth / nSourceAspectRatio
    Dim bmDest As New Bitmap(bmsource, TargetWidth, TargetHeight)
    Return bmDest
End Function

End Class
```

I am using the output of this handler as the source of `img` for example:

```
<img alt="" src="ImageResizer.ashx?image=[path_to_image]&w=100" />
```

This code works fine and displays the image correctly when running on local machine!

I applied this logic to a home page that loops over the database records and loads around 30 images (One image in each `For` loop). Around 90% of the images load and the rest 10% display as blank images (in a random order). The 10% that does not load is distributed (Not consecutive in the `For` loop). For example, it could be as follows:

```
Image #1
Image #2 (Loads as blank)
Image #3
.
.
.
Image #27
Image #28
Image #29 (Loads as blank)
Image #30
```

On another page load it could load as follows:

```
Image #1
Image #2 
Image #3 
.
.
.
Image #27 (Loads as blank)
Image #28 (Loads as blank)
Image #29 
Image #30
```

In the Chrome's console log, the blank images return a 403 error. Note that If I right click those images and open them in a new tab, they display correctly! I tried using different browsers and I got the same results.

What is the reason behind that?

- Could it be a memory issue?
- Could it be that a page is loading faster than another page?
- Could be something related to cache? Like the image name is stored as a timestamp and maybe the CDN cache is trying to load the image from the previous `Page_Load` ?
- Could it be that the handler `ImageResizer.ashx` is loading faster than the page showing the image for example?

Is there anything missing in my code like clearing the memory stream or disposing of any other thing?

Comment: Do you clear the response before doing the save? I usually do: Clear response, Add Header, Add ContentType, Save, End Response, Close Response.  Because sometime a response gets sent half way.

Comment: From your note, is seems like it could be a caching problem. Does it happen on a device that access your page for the first time?

Comment: @the_lotus I tried clearing the response before the save as you suggested but the page still shows some blank images. However, the number of blanks decreased somehow. Not sure though if it is due to clearing the response before save.

Comment: Have you also tried changing to order of things?

Comment: @the_lotus You mean the order of End, Close, Clear... ?
by the way I don't think it is cache because the same thing happens when I reload the page.

Comment: @the_lotus I noticed that it happens to images being loaded outside the mobile screen viewport (Not all images though). Images that are on the viewport load well everytime. The images that you need to scroll down to view sometimes load sometimes not.

Comment: I'm out of ideas at this point, sorry :(

Comment: 1) It should be an .ashx handler instead of an .aspx page - the former doesn't have as many overheads. 2) Have you tried removing the `Page.Response.End()` line?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried a generic handler and removing 'Page.Response.End()'. Still no luck! The output works fine with one image. It just messes up when used in a 'for' loop. Locally, everything is perfect! Weird.

Comment: @RamiZebian Could it be that it is fast enough that more than one image gets the same filename from `DateTime.UtcNow().ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`? You can use "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff" to get fractional seconds too.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Nice idea, but unfortunately it didn't work. I'm out of ideas and most probably it is a caching issue. I am accessing the page via CDN (Content Delivery Network) which optimizes images. It must be something from their side most probably. I think I will revert back to the regular image source and let the CDN do its work for optimizing images instead of doing it myself. Thanks for the support.